# Rolling average matching cases across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm sorry if this has been asked but I can't find another question like this.

I have a data frame in Pandas like this:

```
Home   Away   Home_Score   Away_Score
MIL    NYC    1            2
ATL    NYC    1            3
NYC    PHX    2            1
HOU    NYC    1            6
```

I want to calculate the moving average for each team, but the catch is that I want to do it for all of their games, both home and away combined.

So for a moving average window of size 3 for 'NYC' the answer should be (2+3+2)/3 for row 1 and then (3+2+6)/3 for row 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exploid `stack` to convert the two columns into one and groupby:

```
(df[['Home_Score','Away_Score']]
   .stack()
   .groupby(df[['Home','Away']].stack().values)
   .rolling(3).mean()
   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
   .unstack()
   .add_prefix('Avg_')
)
```

Output:

```
   Avg_Away_Score  Avg_Home_Score
0             NaN             NaN
1             NaN             NaN
2             NaN        2.333333
3        3.666667             NaN
```

Comment: I'm not following you. What's your expected outcome in this case?

Comment: That's because your sample data is to small: most team, except for NYC does not appear 3 times for rolling. You can pass `min_periods=1` to `rolling(3)` if you want all the values.

Comment: I figured out the problem: the columns get swapped after unstacking. I kept reading it as Home first, and the numbers weren't right, even though your output is correct.

Comment: I know it's been a few months but this solution does almost exactly what I'm looking for. However, I get an error using `.unstack()` like this `Index object has no attribute remove_unused_levels`. Any ideas what's causing it and how it might be fixed?